# VUE JS preview image reset not working after file upload

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the image preview working when an image is selected with the file input. I then upload the image and I reset the preview image and the input file field as they need to reset after the file is uploaded.  Then when I select another image, the preview of that image doesn't work.  What I am doing is setting the variable that its bind to, the image src, to ''.

The following is the upload function

```
upload: function(){

        //Initialize the form data
        let formData = new FormData();

        //Add the form data we need to submit
        formData.append('file', this.imagefile);
        formData.append('journal_id', this.$route.params.id);

        //Make the request to the POST /single-file URL
        axios.post('/journal_charts/upload', formData)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('SUCCESS!');
            //reset the file input to null
            var input = $("#file");
            input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));

            ** //reset the preview image to ''. This basically removes the image tag completely
            this.imageData = ''; **

            this.callGetChartList(this.$route.params.id);
        })
```

The following is the HTML form. You can see v-bind:src="imageData" which I am resetting in the upload function. The image-preview HTML is just dissappearing after the upload

```
<input type="file" id="file" ref="file" name="file" class="btn-file" 
@change="previewImage" accept="image/*">
        <div class="image-preview row" v-if="imageData.length > 0">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img class="image ml-md-3" v-bind:src="imageData">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="ml-md-3" @click="upload">Upload Chart</button>
        </div>
```

The preview image function

```
previewImage: function(event) {
        // Reference to the DOM input element
        var input = event.target;
        // Ensure that you have a file before attempting to read it
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            // create a new FileReader to read this image and convert to base64 format
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Define a callback function to run, when FileReader finishes 
            its job
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                // Note: arrow function used here, so that "this.imageData" 
                refers to the imageData of Vue component
                // Read image as base64 and set to imageData
                this.imageData = e.target.result;
                this.imagefile = input.files[0];
            }
            // Start the reader job - read file as a data url (base64 format)
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Show `previewImage` function.

Comment: previewImage function has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the next piece of code - when you clean up the `input` with the help of the jQuery-clone, you lose all the event bindings for this element, and the `previewImage` method is not called anymore:

```
// reset the file input to null
var input = $("#file");
input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
```

So try `vue.js` way without jQuery:

```
this.$refs.file.value = '';
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/u9rfmhwL/ ]